# Call time prior to answering

Tags: samsung, logging, call-history

---

Version: Android 10
Brand: Samsung
Model: S9

---

Is there a way to log the duration of phone ringing, prior to answering or declining a call?
I'm doing this because someone claims to call me, but terminates the call after 1 second, and I need to prove that.
Thank you!

Comment: Usually, this will be logged as "missed call" if it's already reached to your phone. Though, I think there are some providers that filter the ringing before a few seconds to prevent accidental calls?

Comment: A raw idea would be using an [tag:automation] app like [tag:tasker] to react on the ringing and have it make a copy of logcat to investigate. Before you ask: no, I cannot give you a how-to on this. And for context, see eg [How can I view and examine the Android log](/q/14430/16575) and our [logging tag wiki](/tags/logging/info).